# Chome extension is not setting cookies

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, cookies, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to get a chrome extension to set cookies. The function chrome.cookies.set() gets called but I am not seeing it in the developer tools cookies tab.

My manifest is the following permissions:

```
"permissions": [
    "cookies",
    "*://*.google.com",
    "http://*/*",
    "https://*/*"
  ]
```

My code to set the cookies

```
let cookie = {
    url:"https://www.google.com",
    name: "APISID",
    value : "fdENkN9e8UYPb5Ax/A-GZrP_TZvgiX2kxh",
    domain: ".google.com",
    path : "/",
};
chrome.cookies.set(cookie, function (c) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(c));
    console.log(chrome.extension.lastError);
    console.log(chrome.runtime.lastError);
    });
}
```

Comment: what does the console.log output look like?

Comment: I see an error message in chrome://extensions - `"*://*.google.com"` is a malformed pattern. You need to add `/` like this `"*://*.google.com/"`. With this one fixed your code works and I see the cookie. Also make sure you're not running it in a content script, in which case you need to move it into a background script (or any other full-fledged script like a popup script and so on).

Comment: I have it in popup script. Would that be a problem?

Comment: I think I know what the issues was. I was using incognito mode. Apparently chrome.cookies.set() only works in regular mode not incognito. Lesson learnt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this code does work. However it only works if chrome is in normal mode and not incognito.